# bash shell JSON JQ if adminLock =1 Take the median "domains", how do I write

Tags: json, jq

if `adminLock = 1` Take the median "domains", how do I write

```
{
  "code": 0,
  "message": "成功",
  "data": {
    "recordCount": "128",
    "pageSize": 100,
    "page": 1,
    "pageCount": 2,
    "data": [
      {
        "domainsID": "173652434",
        "nsGroupID": "199",
        "groupID": "78987",
        "domains": "xxx1.com",
        "state": 3,
        "userLock": 0,
        "adminLock": 0,
        "view_type": "1"
      },
      {
        "domainsID": "173652434",
        "nsGroupID": "199",
        "groupID": "78987",
        "domains": "xxx2.com",
        "state": 3,
        "userLock": 0,
        "adminLock": 1,
        "view_type": "1"
      },
      {
        "domainsID": "173205836",
        "nsGroupID": "199",
        "groupID": "78987",
        "domains": "xxx3.com",
        "state": 3,
        "userLock": 0,
        "adminLock": 0,
        "view_type": "1"
      },
      {
        "domainsID": "173205812",
        "nsGroupID": "199",
        "groupID": "78987",
        "domains": "xxx4.com",
        "state": 3,
        "userLock": 0,
        "adminLock": 1,
        "view_type": "1"
      }
    ],
    "nextPage": 2
  }
}
```

I hope to get your help, because I really need it, and the complete crawling code. I am good at using Bash Shell,jq -r code

---

**I want to take the value xxx1.com, groupid combination into an array, how should I do
Want to get such a result**

```
now_array=(["173652434"]="xxx2.com" ["173205812"]="xxx4.com")
```

How should I do thank you

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: What does "median domains" mean?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why do you ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74354631/if-adminlock-1-take-the-median-domains-how-do-i-write-in-the-stitching-arr) twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all `domains` where `adminLock == 1` of the inner array with this code:

```bash
jq -r '.data.data[] | select(.adminLock == 1) | .domains' "$INPUT"
```

**Output**

```
xxx2.com
xxx4.com
```