# if adminLock = 1 take the median "domains", how do I write, in the stitching array

Tags: arrays, json, jq

**I want to take the value xxx1.com, the group value of the group into an array, how should I do want to get such a result**

`{ "code": 0, "message": "成功", "data": { "recordCount": "128", "pageSize": 100, "page": 1, "pageCount": 2, "data": [ { "domainsID": "173652434", "nsGroupID": "199", "groupID": "78987", "domains": "xxx1.com", "state": 3, "userLock": 0, "adminLock": 0, "view_type": "1" }, { "domainsID": "173652434", "nsGroupID": "199", "groupID": "78987", "domains": "xxx2.com", "state": 3, "userLock": 0, "adminLock": 1, "view_type": "1" }, { "domainsID": "173205836", "nsGroupID": "199", "groupID": "78987", "domains": "xxx3.com", "state": 3, "userLock": 0, "adminLock": 0, "view_type": "1" }, { "domainsID": "173205812", "nsGroupID": "199", "groupID": "78987", "domains": "xxx4.com", "state": 3, "userLock": 0, "adminLock": 1, "view_type": "1" } ], "nextPage": 2 } }`

I hope to get your help, because I really need it, and the complete crawling code. I am good at using Bash Shell,jq -r code
`now_array=(["173652434"]="xxx2.com" ["173205812"]="xxx4.com")`
The result I want is like this

Comment: Why do you ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74343931/bash-shell-json-jq-if-adminlock-1-take-the-median-domains-how-do-i-write) twice?

Comment: Also, if you copy your post, at least make sure to include the formatting a helpful editor added for you. That makes the post a lot more readable. See [the help centre's page on formatting](/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but here's how to use jq to filter that JSON according to afield value, then format it to create an associative array in Bash:

```bash
$ declare -A now_array="($(jq -r '
    .data.data[] | select(.adminLock == 1) | @sh "[\(.domainsID)]=\(.domains)"
  ' input.json))"

$ echo "${now_array["173205812"]}"
xxx4.com

$ declare -p now_array
declare -A now_array=([173652434]="xxx2.com" [173205812]="xxx4.com" )
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I may not express it clearly,

I want to get the corresponding value in the JSON code, and the final result is spliced into an array

Comment: @user20438305 Can you improve your question with a sample request along with the expected result? Thank you.

Comment: The value obtained in this way does not seem to be an array, because I cannot loop out the data with fo
correct array:
declare -A now_array_ok=(["173652434"]="${xxx2.com}" ["173205812"]="xxx4.com")
echo "${now_array_ok[1]}" #Could not get value
but you declare the array this way:
declare -A now_array_no=([173652434]="xxx2.com" [173205812]="xxx4.com" )
echo "$now_array_no[1]", #I can't get the data
for i in "${!now_array[@]}";
Including that I can't traverse the data using the fo loop
Where is my problem?

Comment: `jq` cannot produce `Bash` arrays. `jq -r` just produces a textual output (here `['173652434']='xxx2.com' ['173205812']='xxx4.com'`) which is captured by `$(…)`, and implemented into a call to `declare -A` which based on it produces an associative array in `Bash`. Maybe you are not using (a modern version of) `Bash`? Also note that for accessing the items in `Bash` you have tried `echo "$now_array_no[1]"` but that's missing the curly braces after `$` and `]`. Also, you seem to expect using indices instead of keys, for which you'd need an indexed array, not an associative array...